# svn update/delete/commit from command line unix

Tags: svn

I have strange situation.
I have file in the svn repository and in local.
After modification and commit, a new revision on repository is created. History is lost.
But i know the old revision number so i am tried to do svn update,
it deleted the current file(new revision) and added the old file, but i am unable to find this in SVN repository.
When i try svn update with the revision in the repository it deletes the current file and Add the file from repository. Now i am not able to find the previous revision.

```
svn update -r4678 TEST
D    TEST
A    TEST
Updated to revision 4678.

svn update -r285795 TEST
D    TEST
A    TEST
Updated to revision 285795.
```

Revision 285795 exists in svn repository, but it does not have the history.
revision 4678 in not is svn repository.

I am not sure how i got into this situation.

I want the add the file with revision 4678 to repository and upon it the new revision 285795.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mention command line and "unix", so how is `tortisesvn` an appropriate tag? Should be `svn` instead? Would also say that `unix` is not necessarily an approriate tag since this does not seem specific to unix.

Comment: well since the commands were executed from unix, also unix being the client, i mentioned the tag UNIX. Point taken, will remove the unix tag.

Comment: Why would you be updating from revision 4678 to revision 285795? I'm sure that how you got into this situation is that you have no idea how version control works. I'm not sure what it is you're trying to accomplish, unless you're trying somehow to change history to cover up something you've done wrong. Version 4678 is not followed by a new revision that is 201K higher.

Comment: @Ken White I understand how the svn works.... also there is nothing to coverup.... if there is old code some 10 years old.... any never modified and now u have to work on it, it is certainly possible to have a jump of so many revision, these are practically possible i believe you would be knowing this.         Probably you did not understand/ i did not explain in a way u understand.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you did not just modify your file: instead, you deleted the old file and added a new file. Even though they have the same name, for svn they are two completely different (and unrelated) files, so this is the reason you do not see any file history of the new file (where should it come from - it was just newly created!).

If I understand you correctly, you would like to have the file with the contents of the latest commit but with the history of the file preserved. To achieve this, do the following:

1. Undo the commit that added the new file my reverse merging it (ie. `svn merge -c -REV filename`, do NOT forget the dash before the revision number) and commit. You should now have a clean working copy with your old file, including history.
2. Get the changes between the old file and the new file (eg using `diff`) and apply them directly to the file in the working copy. Do NOT do an `svn delete/add`, just modify the file. If you execute `svn st`, you should now see a capital `M` in the first column of the status for the file.
3. Confirm that the contents of the file are the same as the new version of the file that you committed in error previously (ie. if you do a diff between the files, it should come up as empty)
4. Commit the file.

You will end up with the contents of the new file and the history of the old file preserved.

Comment: I will try steps mentioned here. Thanks for the help.